# FIbonacci series using recursion error?

Tags: java

```
public class Fibonacci2 {

static int fib(int n) {
  if(n==1 || n==2) {
    return(1);
  }
  return fib((n-1)+fib(n-2));
}

// Stackoverflow error //
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  int i, n = 7;
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    System.out.println("FIbonaci series" + fib(i));
  }
}
```

This program suffer from runtime exception (stackoverflow) please tell how to deal with it.

Answer (score 5):

You step through the code in your debugger and you will see that

```
return fib((n-1)+fib(n-2));
```

should be

```
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

as what you have is like

```
return fib(fib(n-2));
```

which quickly creates very high levels of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

replace `fib((n-1)+fib(n-2))` with `fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you

```
    public static void fib(int initial, int current, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum = initial + current;
    if (initial == 0) {
        System.out.print(current + " ");
    }
    System.out.print(sum + " ");
    initial = current;
    current = sum;
    if (n > 2) {
        fib(initial, current, n - 1);
    }
}
```